# Dark spot on laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, asus-laptop, laptop-repair

Several weeks ago a darker spot appeared on my screen (as seen in the attached picture, it's right under the "Super User" tab) and it looks as if there was some liquid behind the screen. When I physically press it, it doesn't change its shape and it didn't change its shape since it appeared (around 2 weeks ago). The spot is visible especially on white background and is very weak with black background.

I tried blowing hot air on it and rubbing strong magnet (from a hard disk) but neither helped nor made it change its shape.

**Do you have any ideas what could have caused it?** Additionally, do you know how could it be fixed besides using my warranty? The laptop is 4 months old, Asus UX530UQ.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the dark shadow is immediately visible when you boot the laptop
and when the BIOS is showing on the screen, then this is a hardware
problem with the screen, so there is no other solution than
using the warranty.

If the shadow only exists in Windows,
then you could try the following very limited actions:

1. Update the BIOS
2. Update the driver of the video card
3. Disconnect all peripherals, battery and power, press the power button
   for 15 seconds, then reconnect battery and power and boot.

The chances of success with the above actions are not very high.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I can see the patch/shadow even before the OS is loaded so I assume that it's a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

LCD screens consist of multiple layers that consist of (from back to front): a reflector, backlight, diffuser, bottom polarizing layer, top polarizing layer, filter, and the front glass or plastic.

Normally, these layers are all tightly bonded together during the manufacture of the panel (since they are very thin and must be mounted very precisely). What you are seeing is either a separation occurring between those layers, or they are warping.

Unfortunately, there is absolutely nothing you can do about it.  It's a manufacturing defect plain and simple. If your screen is still under warranty, this is definitely a warranty item.  If not, then you'll have to either buy a new one or learn to live with it.  It may worsen over time, however. There's just no way to tell.

Comment: Yeah, a hardware error as you described it seems like the most probable cause of this problem. I think I'll contact the manufacturer ... thanks for the answer.